# Copy constructor's signature without reference

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor

If I have a Point class, the copy constructor should look like this:

```
Point(const Point &p);
Point(Point &p);
```

However, what if I want to create a constructor, which requires a Point? Why is it considered as copy constructor, instead of a constructor?

```
Point(const Point p)
```

Compiler error: "copy constructor for class "Point" may not have a parameter of type "Point"

Comment: That would make little sense. Constructors are used mainly to initialize. So when you create a point, you want to initialize a point?

Comment: `Point(const Point p)` will cause serious recursion

Comment: 1) How should the compiler distinguish between a function taking `const T` and a function taking `const & T`? 2) Define what a `Point( const Point p )` should do, if not constructing a `Point` by *copying* from `Point p`?

Comment: @DevSolar I love answer disguised as question +1

Comment: @AngelusMortis: Sometimes I feel that my contribution, while possibly *helping* the OP, is just too trivial to be put into an answer. Also, gives the OP the opportunity to just delete his question.

Comment: Well, the question was "why is it considered as a copy ctor?". I don't want to use the incoming Point to initialize my new object, I just want a constructor with a Point parameter. Since I haven't defined the copy constructor, the compiler should call the default one. Anyways I assume the answer is the first point: "the compiler can't distinguish between the 2 function". Please note that my question was really just theoretical, I don't need constructor like this at the moment. I was just curious why is it considered as a copy constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> Point(const Point p)
> ```
>
> Why is it considered as copy constructor, instead of a constructor?

It's not.

As the standard says in §12.8/2:

> A non-template constructor for class `X` is a copy constructor if its
>   first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other
>   parameters have default arguments (...).

In fact, your declaration is **ill-formed**. §12.8/6 says:

> A declaration of a constructor for a class `X` is ill-formed if its
>   first parameter is of type (optionally cv-qualified) `X` and either
>   there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have
>   default arguments.

You do have exactly that: a constructor for a class `Point` whose first parameter is of type `const Point` and there are no other arguments.

This is of course the formal explanation. As others have explained, the practical implication of such a constructor would be infinite recursion.

Perhaps you are concerned about the error message you got. However, there are absolutely **no rules regarding the contents of a diagnostic message** produced by a compiler. It's a quality-of-implementation issue; if your compiler thinks that *copy constructor for class "Point" may not have a parameter of type "Point"* is a good way to convey the problem to its users, then so be it.

Answer (score 12):

You can not have a copy constructor signature to accept the argument by value. The reason is simple - in order to pass parameter by value, you need to invoke copy constructor, which will require to pass parameter by value, and will invoke copy constructor... Welcome to endless recursion.

Compiler is saving you a lot of trouble by not allowing this construct.